# Flutter: show tooltip below Slider

Tags: flutter

This is my function:

```
Widget slider(StateSetter setState) {
    return Slider(
      value: sliderValue,
      max: 3,
      divisions: 3,
      label: translate('difficulty.${stringLevels[sliderValue.toInt()]}'),
      onChanged: (double value) {
        settingsController.updateDifficulty(value.toInt());
        setState(() {
          sliderValue = value;
        });
      },
    );
  }
```

Look ok but I'd like to have the tooltip below the slider, not there at the top:

[image]

Comment: If you plan to have also more customizations on the slider, I would recommend to check out: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_xlider.
Specifically for tooltip you can use `positionOffset` property.

Comment: well, it's just the tooltip. Apart from that I only need the default style, but if it's not possible I could give it a chance

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom ***tooltip*** .Like this:-

```
class SliderWithCustomTooltip extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SliderWithCustomTooltipState createState() => _SliderWithCustomTooltipState();
}

class _SliderWithCustomTooltipState extends State<SliderWithCustomTooltip> {
  double _sliderValue = 0.5;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
  
              Expanded(
                child: Slider(
                  value: _sliderValue,
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    setState(() {
                      _sliderValue = value;
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Tooltip(
          message: 'Value: ${_sliderValue.toStringAsFixed(2)}',
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.black,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
            ),
            child: Text(
              _sliderValue.toStringAsFixed(2),
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: that's just a text showing below the slider, not a tooltip like the one that goes with the pin showing and hidding with every interaction

Comment: try this https://pub.dev/packages/just_the_tooltip

Comment: that's missing the rest of the Slider's behaviour